# c++ template code explain

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

```
template <typename Function>
struct function_traits
    : public function_traits<decltype(&Function::operator())> {
}; //1 why function_traints inherit from itself?

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const> {
    typedef ReturnType (*pointer)(Args...);
    typedef std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> function;
}; //2 this class do nothing just typedef type ?

template <typename Function>
typename function_traits<Function>::function
to_function (Function & lambda) {
    return static_cast<typename function_traits<Function>::function>(lambda);
}

template <typename Lambda>
size_t getAddress(Lambda lambda) {
    auto function = new decltype(to_function(lambda))(to_function(lambda));
    //3 func is std::function pointer,this conversion is ok?  
    void * func = static_cast<void *>(function);
    return (size_t)func;
}

int f(int, int) { return 1; }
int g(int, int) { return 2; }
std::function<int(int, int)> lambda1 = [](int a, int b)->int
{
    return 1;
};
std::function<int(int, int)> lambda2 = [](int a, int b)->int
{
    return 1;
};

void test(std::function<int(int, int)> const& arg,const char* info)
{
    std::cout << "test function: ";
    std::cout << (void*)getAddress(arg) << " " << info << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    test(lambda1,"lambda1");
    test(lambda1,"lambda1");
    test(lambda2,"lambda2");
    test(lambda2,"lambda2");
    test(std::function<int(int, int)>(std::plus<int>()),"plus");
    test(std::function<int(int, int)>(std::minus<int>()),"minus");
    test(std::function<int(int, int)>(f),"f");
    test(std::function<int(int, int)>(g),"g");
}
```

1 why function_traints inherit from itself?

i known this is Curiously recurring template pattern. the function_traints while be compile to two different class.

2 the second class do nothing just typedef type ?

yes, just for convenient

3 func is std::function pointer,this conversion is ok?

[TODO]

4 the main function result is :

```
test function: 0x7f9440407f50 lambda1
test function: 0x7f9440407f80 lambda1
test function: 0x7f9440407fb0 lambda2
test function: 0x7f9440407fe0 lambda2
test function: 0x7f9440408010 plus
test function: 0x7f9440408040 minus
test function: 0x7f9440408070 f
test function: 0x7f94404080a0 g
```

these function above is wrong? i can't use it to check whether two function is equal?

[TODO]

Can you explain the code above? Thank you very much!

Comment: "i known this is Curiously recurring template pattern" - This is not CRTP.

Answer (score 2):

> why function_traints inherit from itself?

It doesn't. `Function` and `decltype(&Function::operator())` are different types, thus `function_traits<Function>` and `function_traits are also different and unrelated types.

> the second class do nothing just typedef type ?

Yes. This is normal for a traits class. In this case, function_traits provides unifirm access to the return type of a callable object, regardless of what this object is: a function pointer, a pointer  to member, a lambda or anything else.

> func is std::function pointer,this conversion is ok?

No, the conversion is not OK. There are at least three problems with it:

1. You cannot convert just any lambda to a function pointer, only non-capturing lambdas.
2. There is a memory leak (the dynamic allocation is totally unnecessary).
3. A function pointer is in general not compatible with `void*` and `void*` is not compatible with `size_t`. This code may work on some platfirms but not on others.

Comment: thank you very much!  there is another doubt：   <br>
func is std::function pointer,this conversion is ok?     <br>
please explain the static_cast. thank you!  ^V^

Comment: oh.   i see.   thanks again!  ^V^